# SpringBoot2 + Webflux - WebTestClient always returns “401 UNAUTHORIZED”

Tags: spring, spring-boot, junit, spring-security, spring-webflux

I am trying to write some test using WebTestClient under Springboot 2.1.8 and Junit5

It's always returning < 401 UNAUTHORIZED Unauthorized, but actually it didn't go to the controller or service layer at all. It may related to spring security, just my guess.

The project was generated using JHipster. Here is the [build.gradle](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1zG74X5YfZeNP-M3wqcuPqHYtPDJCD5Fs)

-----------------UimApiServiceImplTest.java-------------------

```java
...


@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@WebFluxTest(controllers = UserGuidController.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {UserGuidController.class, UimApiServiceImpl.class})

public class UimApiServiceImplTest {

    @Autowired
    private WebTestClient webTestClient;

    @Test
    public void testGetGuidByEmail() {

        webTestClient.get()
            .uri("/uimapi/getguid/{email}", "someone@xxxxx.com")
            .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8)
            .exchange()
            .expectStatus().isOk();
    }
}
```

--------------------UserGuidController.java--------------------

```java
...
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/uimapi")
public class UserGuidController {

    @Autowired
    private UimApiServiceImpl uimApiService;

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(UserGuidController.class);

    @GetMapping("/getguid/{email}")
    public String getUserGuid(@PathVariable String email) {
        return uimApiService.getUserGuid(email);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please share your pom file

Comment: I've updated it above. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 12):

For webflux, you can disable SecurityAutoconfiguration by excluding the ReactiveSecurityAutoConfiguration class like this:

```
@WebFluxTest(controllers = YourController.class,excludeAutoConfiguration = {ReactiveSecurityAutoConfiguration.class}))
```

Comment: It worked perfectly, thanks! This should be marked as solution...

Comment: disabling security is not really a good practice, as a matter of fact there should be tests that make sure your specific controller api actually fails in that way. For the happy path you could use `@Mock...` or `mutateWith`, have a look at the [docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/reactive/test/web/authentication.html):

Answer (score 8):

You've `implementation "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security`" in your gradle dependencies. Spring boot automatically enables security on all endpoints by default when this dependency is found in classpath.

You can choose to disable this default configuration by updating your main class:

```
@SpringBootApplication(exclude = { SecurityAutoConfiguration.class, ManagementWebSecurityAutoConfiguration.class })
```

This would disable security on all endpoints.

If you want to have control of which endpoints to remove security from, you can do that using the below code with updates matching your requirements:

```
@Configuration
public class SecurityConfiguration {

  @Bean
  public SecurityWebFilterChain securityFilterChain(ServerHttpSecurity http) {
    http.authorizeExchange().anyExchange().permitAll();
    return http.build();
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help!