# Junit Testing for Reactive Java failing with "Expected :200 OK , Actual :404 NOT_FOUND"

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-webflux, reactive-programming, junit5

Following is my controller class

```
@RestController
public class FluxAndMonoController {

    @GetMapping("/flux")
    public Flux<Integer> returnFlux(){

        return Flux.just(1, 2, 3, 4)
                .delayElements(Duration.ofSeconds(1))
                .log();
    }

    @GetMapping(value = "/fluxstream", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_NDJSON_VALUE)    
    public Flux<Integer> returnFluxStream(){ 

        return Flux.just(1, 2, 3, 4)
                .delayElements(Duration.ofSeconds(1))
                .log();
    }

}
```

And following is my test for the above controller's first endpoint ('/flux')

```
@WebFluxTest
public class FluxAndMonoController {

    @Autowired
    WebTestClient webTestClient;    

    @Test
    public void flux_approach1(){

        Flux<Integer> integerFlux = webTestClient.get().uri("/flux")
                .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                .exchange() 
                .expectStatus().isOk()
                .returnResult(Integer.class)
                .getResponseBody();

        StepVerifier.create(integerFlux)
                .expectSubscription()
                .expectNext(1)
                .expectNext(2)
                .expectNext(3)
                .expectNext(4)
                .verifyComplete();
    }
}
```

On running the test, I am receiving the error-

```
< 404 NOT_FOUND Not Found
< Content-Type: [application/json]
< Content-Length: [131]

{"timestamp":"2023-03-17T13:08:45.647+00:00","path":"/flux","status":404,"error":"Not Found","message":null,"requestId":"7e94e64e"}


Status expected:<200 OK> but was:<404 NOT_FOUND>
Expected :200 OK
Actual   :404 NOT_FOUND
<Click to see difference>

java.lang.AssertionError: Status expected:<200 OK> but was:<404 NOT_FOUND>
```

I have tried adding @ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
annotation on the controllerTest, but it is not making any difference.
Kindly suggest some ideas to overcome this error. Thank you

P.S.: From postman and browser, the endpoint '/flux' is working fine. The status on postman is 200OK and I'm getting the output as well

Comment: Cannot reproduce based on given classes, only change is following https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58348038/springboot2-webflux-webtestclient-always-returns-401-unauthorized to avoid 401

Answer (score 0):

```java
@SpringBootTest
class FluxAndMonoControllerTest {


    WebTestClient webTestClient;

    @Autowired
    ApplicationContext context;

    @BeforeEach
    public void setup() {
        this.webTestClient = WebTestClient
                .bindToApplicationContext(this.context)
                .configureClient()
                .build();
    }
    @Test
    void returnFlux() {

        Flux<Integer> response = webTestClient.get().uri("/flux")
                .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                .exchange()
                .expectStatus().isOk()
                .returnResult(Integer.class)
                .getResponseBody();

        StepVerifier.create(response)
                .expectNext(1)
                .expectNext(2)
                .expectNext(3)
                .expectNext(4)
                .verifyComplete();
    }

    @Test
    void returnFluxStream() {

        Flux<Integer> response = webTestClient.get().uri("/fluxstream")
                .accept(MediaType.valueOf(MediaType.APPLICATION_NDJSON_VALUE))
                .exchange()
                .expectStatus().isOk()
                .returnResult(Integer.class)
                .getResponseBody();

        StepVerifier.create(response)
                .expectNext(1)
                .expectNext(2)
                .expectNext(3)
                .expectNext(4)
                .verifyComplete();
    }
}
```